# How to take three inputs in python where two of them are optional

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I have tried starting the variable and using the split method. But I get errors that I can not use stared variable more than once. Now how can I take 3 inputs in a line where two of them are optional.
'''

```
lst = []
n = int(input())
i = 0

while i < n:
    x, *y, *z = input().split()
    y = y if y else ''
    z = z if z else ''
    y = int(y)

    if x == 'insert':
        lst.insert(y,z)
print(lst)
```

'''

Comment: What does it means  ```two inputs are optional```

Comment: Use `try-except` for reading

Comment: BTW dont use *y, *z, just write it simply as y, z

Comment: Please tell me what does it means optional in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your program, not only input loading.

```
lst = []
n = int(input())

for i in range(n): # preventing infinite loop
    args = input().split()
    x = args[0]
    y = args[1] if len(args) > 1 else '0' # empty string is not a valid number
    z = args[2] if len(args) > 2 else ''
    y = int(y)

    if x == 'insert':
        lst.insert(y,z)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starred expressions play several roles: they describe optional arguments **In function definition** or describe unpacking of sequences of variable length (as if in this case) https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#id4.
What you probably want to do, is something like that:

```
lst = []
n = int(input())
i = 0

while i < n:
    data = input().split()
    x = data[0]
    if len(data) > 1:
       y, z = data[1: 3]
       y = y if y else ''
       z = z if z else ''

    if x == 'insert':
        lst.insert(y,z)
    i += 1
print(lst)
```